# EOFError due to prompting the user input in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to execute the above code using Python 2.7. I get `EOFError`.

```
def perfectNumberCheck(num):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            sum = sum + i
    if sum == num:
        print('1')
    else:
        print('0')


num = int(raw_input('come on dude:'))
perfectNumberCheck(num)
```

I have no problem in Python 3 but need to submit the assignment in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

When your os automatically calls the script in the background, there is no STDIN into the script, thus it receives an unexpected end-of-file (because, technically, stdin=/dev/null , which will always give eof).
As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833748/6225617) you can try the following part:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line

sys.stdin = open('CON', 'r')
num = raw_input("come on dude:")
perectNumberCheck(num)
```

Comment: i am still getting the same error. I have no problem in python 3 but need to submit the asssignment in python 2. plz help me.