# How to use `input()` after reading a file from `stdin`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, scripting

## Context

I want a simple script that selects 1 of multiple piped inputs without `EOF when reading a line` error on Unix/Linux.

It tries to:

1. accept multiple lines of piped text
2. wait for user to select one option
3. print that option to stdout

## Desired usage:

```
$ printf "A\nB" | ./select.py | awk '{print "OUTPUT WAS: " $0}'
Select 0-1:
  0) A
  1) B
> 1
OUTPUT WAS: B
```

The `awk '{print "[OUTPUT WAS] " $0}'` at the end is just to show that the only stdout output should be the selection.

## Current approach:

```py
#!/bin/python3
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

def print_options(options):
    """print the user's options"""
    print(f"Select 0-{len(options)-1}:", file=sys.stderr)
    for n, option in options.items():
        print(f"  {n}) {option}", file=sys.stderr)

def main():
    # options are stored in an ordered dictionary to make order consistent
    options = OrderedDict()
    # read in the possible options one line at a time
    for n, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
        options[n] = line.rstrip('\n')
        
    valid_selection = False
    # loop until we get a valid selection
    while not valid_selection:
        print_options(options)
        try:
            print('> ', end='', file=sys.stderr)
            selection = int(input()) # <- doesn't block like it should
            # use the selection to extract the output that will be printed
            output = options[selection]
            valid_selection = True
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Invalid selection. {e}", file=sys.stderr)
                
    print(output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Error:

The script gets trapped in an infinite loop printing:

```
...
> Invalid selection. EOF when reading a line
Select 0-1:
  0) A
  1) B
> Invalid selection. EOF when reading a line
Select 0-1:
  0) A
  1) B
> Invalid selection. EOF when reading a line
...
```

### Minimum script to reproduce error:

```py
#!/bin/python3
import sys

options = []
# read in the possible options one line at a time
for line in sys.stdin:
    options.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
    
user_input = input('> ')
            
print(user_input)
```

This throws:

```
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

When I want to see and input:

```
$ printf "text" | ./testscript.py
> sometext
sometext
```

## Desired solution:

I gather this is due to the fact that stdin has reached an EOF. But my question is how to reset/remove the impact of the EOF so that `input()` once again blocks and waits for the user like it normally would.

In short: **how to use `input()` after reading a file from `stdin`?**

If that's impossible, [as this answer implies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833677/7872793), what elegant solutions are there to get similar behavior to what I describe at the beginning of this question? I'm open to non-python solutions (e.g. bash|zsh, rust, awk, perl).

Comment: @user That's not correct. If you check the while loop, its stanza says `while not valid_selection:` Check the minimum script to reproduce the error I'm trying to fix. Edit: the user removed their comment, but I'm going to leave this here for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer your question for Linux/Unix OS. I'm sorry, I do not work with Windows.

I added two lines to your example code, see below.

The special device `/dev/tty` is connected to your terminal. It is your standard input/output unless redirected. Basically you want to restore the state that your stdin is connected to your terminal. On the low level it works with file descriptor 0. The `close` closes it and the `open` takes the first free one which is in that case the 0.

```
import sys 

options = []
# read in the possible options one line at a time
for line in sys.stdin:
    options.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

# restore input from the terminal   
sys.stdin.close()
sys.stdin=open('/dev/tty')

user_input = input('> ')
                 
print(user_input)
```

Comment: In the rare case the /dev/tty isn't the controlling terminal, then `os.ctermid()` may return the right one.

Comment: @tdelaney Could you please give an example? A process may have no controlling terminal, but if it has one, how can `/dev/tty` be wrong?

Comment: @VPID Many systems define "/dev/tty" to alias the controlling terminal. On my laptop, `os.ctermid()` returns "/dev/tty" while `os.ttyname(1)` is "/dev/pty/X". The linux [ctermid man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctermid.3.html) is coy, saying _it may, for example, be /dev/tty_. On some systems its defined to always be "/dev/tty", but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @tdelaney is `os.ctermid()` a preferable alternative to /dev/tty?

Comment: @Connor - good question! I think so, but I've worked in many environments, sometimes using multiple session group headers and ttys. Poking around, freebsd seems to canonically define /dev/tty as correct. GNU says _In the GNU C Library, it returns the same string all the time: "/dev/tty"_, but the linux docs generally are not as committed. Do all linux's or linuxy things conform? I don't know. Back in the day, _ctermid_ was _the_ way to do it. Nowadays it may be more vestigial, but to me it still makes sense to call `ctermid` and make it the operating system's problem.

Comment: I understand the `ctermid` as a POSIX standardization of the established `/dev/tty` meaning. I don't think there could exist a Unix-like system using `/dev/tty` for something else. It would break a lot of programs.

Answer (score 0):

[VPfB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66143581/7872793) is what I needed, here's the finalized script in case anyone would like to use it.

## Usage

```
$ printf "A\nB\nC" | ./select.py | awk '{print "Selected: " $0}'
Select 0-1:
  0) A
  1) B
  2) C
> 2 <- your input
Selected: C
```

## Full Solution

```py
#!/bin/python3
"""
A simple script to allow selecting 1 of multiple piped inputs. 

Usage: 
printf "A\nB" | ./choose.py

If your input is space separated, make sure to convert with: 
printf "A B" | sed 's+ +\n+g' | ./choose.py

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66143667/7872793
"""
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

def print_options(options):
    """print the user's options"""
    print(f"Select 0-{len(options)-1}:", file=sys.stderr)
    for n, option in options.items():
        print(f"  {n}) {option}", file=sys.stderr)

def select_loop(options):
    valid_selection = False
    # loop until we get a valid selection
    while not valid_selection:
        print_options(options)
        try:
            print('> ', end='', file=sys.stderr)
            selection = int(input())
            # use the selection to extract the output that will be printed
            output = options[selection]
            valid_selection = True
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Invalid selection. {e}", file=sys.stderr)
            
    return output

def main():
    # options are stored in an ordered dictionary to fix iteration output
    options = OrderedDict()
    # read in the possible options one line at a time
    for n, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
        options[n] = line.rstrip('\n')
        
    # restore input from the terminal
    sys.stdin.close()
    sys.stdin=open('/dev/tty')
        
    # if only one option is given, use it immediately
    output = options[0] if len(options) == 1 else select_loop(options)
    print(output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```