# input() after readlines() from sys.stdin?

Tags: python, console, pipe, stdin, readlines

I have a case where my script calls `readlines()` on `sys.stdin` followed by a call to `input()`, but that last call won't work.

Here's my script:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument('data', type=click.File())
def inp(data):
    lines = data.readlines()
    print('Read {} lines. Continue?'.format(len(lines)))
    choice = input().lower()
    print("You said '{}'.".format(choice))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inp()
```

The script works fine if the user specified an actual file argument on the command line, but not if they pipe input data and use the `-`:

```
head -n10 data.txt | python3 script.py -  
Read 10 lines. Continue?
Aborted!
```

I need to support the `-` reading followed by `input()` -- how can I make it work?

Comment: If input is being piped to the program, then `stdin` is obviously not connected to a terminal - there's no place for `input()` to receive characters from.

Comment: Can I reconnect `stdin` to the terminal after the readlines() call has finished?

Comment: Perhaps you could do something like `sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty')` (on Unix-ish systems, at least).

Answer (score 0):

**to save our time, u are free to jump to the bottom to see the *conclusion***

### Start

I am searching for the answer to the question as u did.

**At First, I think the following will solve the problem...**

> multiple piped inputs without EOF

[How to use `input()` after reading a file from `stdin`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66142884/how-to-use-input-after-reading-a-file-from-stdin?noredirect=1&lq=1)

*however, it does not succeed in my computer,
and thus, I try to figure out how to exactly clear the EOF mark...*

> Terminate/Break/Abort Python Console/sys.stdin readline()

[How do you terminate/break/abort a Python console/sys.stdin readline()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515478/how-do-you-terminate-break-abort-a-python-console-sys-stdin-readline)

> flush

[How to flush the input stream in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520893/how-to-flush-the-input-stream-in-python)

*In C Language, we use fflush(stdin), ..etc to clear the buffer*

*In C++ Language, we use std::cin.get(), ..etc to clear the buffer*

*But How About Python Language ??*

**After Searching For 2 hours, I realize Python so far does not provide this function, clear the buffer/EOF in the stdin**

**And the answers available online which succeed like this one**
[How to use `input()` after reading a file from `stdin`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66142884/how-to-use-input-after-reading-a-file-from-stdin?noredirect=1&lq=1) **are only suitable for Linux System**

> After Reading This

https://www.twblogs.net/a/5c0ac824bd9eee6fb21399d4

*I am so sure(i think) that Python in Windows cannot use **input** after **stdin is taken by file**

*However, does that mean, we should batter the sys.stdin method?*

*No, Obviously, or I won't spend my time here typing...*

### **And Here Is My Final Method To Solve The Problem**

> re-Create Your **Own Input** as follow

```
def new_input(): ## version 1
import msvcrt
str_=''
c=msvcrt.getche()
while ord(c)!=3 and ord(c)!=4 and ord(c)!=26 and ord(c)!=13:
    # print(ord(c))
    str_ = str_+str(c)[2:-1]
    c=msvcrt.getche()
return str_

def new_input(interact_string_): ## version 2
import msvcrt
print(interact_string_, end ="")
str_=''
c=msvcrt.getche()
while ord(c)!=3 and ord(c)!=4 and ord(c)!=26 and ord(c)!=13:
    # print(ord(c))
    str_ = str_+str(c)[2:-1]
    c=msvcrt.getche()
return str_

def new_input(interact_string_): ## version 3
import msvcrt
import os
print(interact_string_, end ="")
str_=''
print('')
c=msvcrt.getche()
while ord(c)!=3 and ord(c)!=4 and ord(c)!=26 and ord(c)!=13:
    os.system('cls')
    print(interact_string_, end ="")
    # print(ord(c))
    if ord(c)==8:
        str_ = str_[0:-1]
        print(str_)
    else:
        str_ = str_+str(c)[2:-1]
        print(str_)
    c=msvcrt.getche()
# print(str_)
return str_
```

***Here, are the meanings of numbers***

- ord(c)==3 will be the key of **Ctrl+C**
- ord(c)==4 will be the key of **Ctrl+D**
- ord(c)==26 will be the key of **Ctrl+Z**
- ord(c)==13 will be the key of **Enter**
- ord(c)==22 will be the key of **Ctrl+C**
- ord(c)==8 will be the key of **Backspace**

*And it will still be convenient to using **if-structure** to react with, and returns the final string*

---

### Conclusion:

1. after using stdin to readlines()/readline()/read() to read a file you **cannot ever** using stdin to input/output in **Windows System**
2. while, in the same case, the Same Problem on **Linux System** is solvable, and the answer will be up there...
3. In my opinion and under my research, The Best Answer to **Windows** will be **mine** *(of course will I say that..)* . ++==> **re-Create your input()**

##### Thanks For Your Reading, constructive advice and polite comment is welcomed. Anyone With a Better Idea or Solve is welcome too.

##### *like it if u enjoy the journey with me while reading **my adventure to finding answer***