# Can i use input after sys.stdin read a file ? (in Windows System)

Tags: python

After using **stdin.read()/stdin.readlines()/stdin.readlines()**, every following **input** will not work(it will show off EOF error,) beacuse input() is set to prevent the **EOF** reading.
However, isn't there any way to clean the sys.stdin() buffer?
[code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKzPQ.png)

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Why are you trying to interact with stdin in this way?

Comment: If a program reads `stdin` until it reaches EOF, that is a pattern where the program runs to completion from a command line and its input has been redirected to `stdin` using `<`. In that case there is no need to continue to read from `stdin` afterwards. If, on the other hand, you want your program to interact with the user, then don't take initialization data from `stdin` and instead read it from a file named on the command line. And use `input()` to get data from `stdin` in preference to using file operations like `read()`. Not because they won't work but because that is not a Python idiom.

Answer (score -1):

> Here is the link to the Delete Post

[input() after readlines() from sys.stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66182398/input-after-readlines-from-sys-stdin/68420268#68420268)

the answer is **no**, but there may be a way to re-construct your **input** by using **wsvcrt** module

## Just In Case For The Deleted Page Will Never Be Seen

[pic one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz9aS.png)

[pic two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0p4l.png)

[pic three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJTo6.png)